# Как правильно написать интервальное числительное словами?

Tags: числительные

Как правильно написать 6-10-метровый? **Шести-десятиметровый** будет верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, предложенное Вами написание верно.

В орфографическом словаре Лопатина "Слитно раздельно или через дефис" имеются многочисленные примеры типа: *двадцати-тридцатилетний (20-30-летний); десяти-пятнадцатиметровый (10—15-метровый)*. Как видим из этих примеров, в словесном выражении используется дефисное написание вне зависимости от того, какое правило действует для цифрового написания. В этом есть простая и правильная, я считаю, логика.

Также замечу, что в технической литературе в добротных изданиях находятся многочисленные примеры с дефисным написанием (при этом мне не попалось ни одного примера с тире).

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что если это **пять — десять метров** (как в примере у Александра), то тире, а если **пяти-десятиметровый**, то дефис?

Comment: @Юлия Я считаю, что Вы понимаете правильно. Но я согласен с Александром, что такое написание может сбивать с толку. Поэтому я рекомендовал бы избегать потенциальных недоразумений и формулировать фразу иначе.

Comment: Как например? Уместно ли будет написать это цифрами в худ.литературе?

Comment: @Юлия Можно сказать "от шести до десяти метров" или "шесть — десять метров". Цифрами в худ. литературе не рекомендуют, но даже это будет меньшим злом, я думаю.

Comment: Меньшим злом :) Мне понравилось) Спасибо за ответ, он мне тоже понравился)

Answer (score 3):

Правильно так: ***6—10-метровый*** (с тире между цифрами, но без пробелов)
 и ***шести — десятиметровый*** (тире с пробелами).

[**6.1.5. Интервал значений**](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091464.html#id-6%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-615%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

> **Обозначение интервала значений.** Для обозначения интервала значений ставят: а) многоточие; б) **тире**; в) знак ÷; г) предлог *от* перед первым числом и *до* — перед вторым. Напр.: *Длиной 5... 10 метров; Длиной **5—10** метров; Длиной 5÷10 метров; Длиной от 5 до 10 метров.*
>
> **Употребление тире**. Тире в качестве знака интервала значений рекомендуется ставить:
>
> 1. При словесной форме чисел (прописью) в изданиях худож. лит., а также близких к ней. Напр.: *...длиной **пять — десять** метров.* При этом, как и обычно между словами, тире, по техн. правилам набора, должно быть отбито от слов на 2 п., что и должно быть обозначено в оригинале.

Comment: Александр, не будете ли вы так добры и не посмотрите ли мой второй вопрос про однородные члены предложения? :)

Comment: @Юлия  Я видел вопрос, но там нужно побольше времени. Если никто не ответит, постараюсь посмотреть.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо) Я на самом деле, думала, что там элементарно, просто мой пробел в знаниях не позволяет мне увидеть, в чём там дело.

Comment: Я могу допустить написание с тире только в таком случае: "шестиметровый — десятиметровый". Если бы Вы предложили что-то такое: "шести- — десятиметровый", я ещё мог бы понять (но не принять). Ваш вариант мне кажется совершенно недопустимым. Неужели где-то такое видели?

Comment: @grizzly  В научной литературе вообще не используют  буквенное написание (или используют очень редко). Я ориентировался на правила, где говорится, что дефис применяется для примерных значений (_пяти-семи лет, десять-двенадцать метров_), но там нет прямых указаний для интервалов с прилагательными, в состав которых входят числительные.  Поэтому мне бы не хотелось, чтобы последние уподоблялись дефисному написанию: _шести-десятиметровый_  выглядит как _то ли шесть, то ли восемь, то ли десять_ или вообще как ошибка в _шестидесятиметровом_.  Может для таких прилагательных сделали исключение? :)

Comment: Ок, не буду спорить, просто оставлю здесь [эту ссылку](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=*%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9*).

Comment: Александр, я надеюсь, что вы не будете на меня в обиде. Я приняла другой ответ. Я встречалась с подобной реакцией здесь и, признаться, не знаю, как быть в таких ситуациях. Не знаю вашего отношения к репутации вашего аккаунта на данном ресурсе. Я очень извиняюсь.

Comment: @Юлия  Нет, что вы!  Всегда нужно подождать, чтобы выбрать наиболее для себя приемлемый ответ. Спасибо за вопрос.

Comment: Фух :) Спасибо Вам за ответ) И за ответы на другие мои вопросы)